# Delete mapping values in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I created mapping `address-> uint` and i need to make whole `mapping -> uints` values set to 0  is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

> i need to make whole mapping -> uints values set to 0

If you're talking about immediately after creation, they already are.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/types.html?highlight=types#mapping-types

> "You can think of mappings as hash tables, which are virtually
> initialised such that every possible key exists and is mapped to a
> value whose byte-representation is all zeros, a type’s default value."

If you're talking about later on, after the mapping has been used, then you'll need a way to record which addresses have had non-zero values set.

See [Clearing Mappings](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/security-considerations.html#clearing-mappings) in the official docs.